# Gitflow Workflow - What Git command can prevent feature branches to be pushed

Tags: git, branch

I use Git 2.13, SourceTree 2, and Bitbucket Cloud on a Windows machine.

I'm studying Gitflow workflow, [written by nvie](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), and this part is what I'm struggling with.

> "Feature branches typically exist in developer repos only, not in origin."

When using SorceTree, all my feature branches (f0, f1, f2, ...) are pushed to my Bitbucket Cloud repository.

Using whether the Git command line or SourceTree, how can I prevent those feature branches to be pushed to the remote repository using what Git command?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no command to prevent that, you just have not to use `git push feature-branch origin`. 
Instead you merge your features into the development branch and push that to the origin.

If you use git flow plugin, this is easy to achieve:

```
# create a feature branch
git flow feature start my-new-feature

# develop your feature and create commits

# when you are ready merge back the feature
git flow feature finish my-new-feature
```